# what does "bash:no job control in this shell” mean?

Tags: linux, bash

I think it's related to the parent process creating new subprocess and does not have tty. Can anyone explain the detail under the hood? i.e. the related working model of bash, process creation, etc?

It may be a very broad topic so pointers to posts are also very appreciated. I've Googled for a while, all the results are about very specific case and none is about the story behind the scene. To provide more context, below is the shell script resulting the 'bash: no job control in this shell'.

```
#! /bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
    st=$(netstat -an |grep 7070 |grep LISTEN -o | uniq)
    if [ -z $st ]; then
        echo "need to start proxy @$(date)"
        bash -i -c "ssh -D 7070 -N user@my-ssh.example.com > /dev/null"
    else
        echo "proxy OK @$(date)"
    fi
    sleep 3
done
```

This line:

`bash -i -c "ssh -D 7070 -N user@my-ssh.example.com > /dev/null"`

is where "bash:no job control in this shell” come from.

Comment: I can't tell from your question whether you want information on job control in the shell in general, or an explanation for why job control would be unavailable under some circumstances.

Comment: Both of them :) It may be a very broad topic so pointers to posts are also very appreciated. I've Googled for a while, all the results are about very specific case and none is about the story behind the scene.

Comment: Is there a reason you're starting a new shell to launch SSH? Running your script from command line doesn't give me "no jobs control", although it just hangs on SSH execution, which it actually is supposed to do. So technically, the "else" won't ever be hit. Where are you running this script from? crontab?

Comment: @luanjunyi since you ask, here is [my favorite article on the subject of process management in the shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 119):

You may need to enable job control:

```
#! /bin/bash   
set -m
```

Comment: _WHAAAAAAAT?_ Why isn't that the default?

Comment: Works great in Docker Containers! Doing background job for the container's entrypoint and then bringing it back up. Feeding data to databases that don't have support to seeding from files...

Comment: *AMAZING!* Works on GitHub Actions runners as well!

Comment: Thanks, but please explain what "job control" means to answer 'What does "bash:no job control in this shell” mean?'

Comment: I believe that another answer in the very same thread has already provided the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824420/8471555

Comment: @MarcellodeSales Its funny how, I was trying to solve that exact problem, and it led me to this question

Comment: Also works in _Makefile_ where job control seems to be turned off.

Comment: After adding 'set-m' to a script, I now get the error 'fg: %: no such job' instead of the original error.

Comment: Also, the `set -m` needs to come before the first `bg` for the `fg` to work.

Answer (score 72):

**Job control** is a collection of features in the shell and the tty driver which allow the user to manage multiple jobs from a single interactive shell.

A job is a single command or a pipeline. If you run `ls`, that's a job. If you run `ls|more`, that's still just one job. If the command you run starts subprocesses of its own, then they will also belong to the same job unless they are intentionally detached.

Without job control, you have the ability to put a job in the background by adding `&` to the command line. And that's about all the control you have.

With job control, you can additionally:

1. Suspend a running foreground job with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>
2. Resume a suspended job in the foreground with `fg`
3. Resume a suspend job in the background with `bg`
4. Bring a running background job into the foreground with `fg`

The shell maintains a list of jobs which you can see by running the `jobs` command. Each one is assigned a job number (distinct from the PIDs of the process(es) that make up the job). You can use the job number, prefixed with `%`, as an argument to `fg` or `bg` to select a job to foreground or background. The %jobnumber notation is also acceptable to the shell's builtin `kill` command. This can be convenient because the job numbers are assigned starting from 1, so they're shorter than PIDs.

There are also shortcuts `%+` for the most recently foregrounded job and `%-` for the previously foregrounded job, so you can switch back and forth rapidly between two jobs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> followed by `fg %-` (suspend the current one, resume the other one) without having to remember the numbers. Or you can use the beginning of the command itself. If you have suspended an `ffmpeg` command, resuming it is as easy as `fg %ff` (assuming no other active jobs start with "ff"). And as one last shortcut, you don't have to type the `fg`. Just entering `%-` as a command foregrounds the previous job.

"But why do we need this?" I can hear you asking. "I can just start another shell if I want to run another command." True, there are many ways of multitasking. On a normal day I have login shells running on tty1 through tty10 (yes there are more than 6, you just have to activate them), one of which will be running a screen session with 4 screens in it, another might have an ssh running on it in which there is another screen session running on the remote machine, plus my X session with 3 or 4 xterms. And I still use job control.

If I'm in the middle of `vi` or `less` or `aptitude` or any other interactive thing, and I need to run a couple of other quick commands to decide how to proceed, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, run the commands, and `fg` is natural and quick. (In lots of cases an interactive program has a `!` keybinding to run an external command for you; I don't think that's as good because you don't get the benefit of your shell's history, command line editor, and completion system.) I find it sad whenever I see someone launch a secondary xterm/screen/whatever to run one command, look at it for two seconds, and then exit.

Now about this script of yours. In general it does not appear to be competently written. The line in question:

```
bash -i -c "ssh -D 7070 -N user@my-ssh.example.com > /dev/null"
```

is confusing. I can't figure out why the ssh command is being passed down to a separate shell instead of just being executed straight from the main script, let alone why someone added `-i` to it. The `-i` option tells the shell to run interactively, which activates job control (among other things). But it isn't actually being used interactively. Whatever the purpose was behind the separate shell and the `-i`, the warning about job control was a side effect. I'm guessing it was a hack to get around some undesirable feature of ssh. That's the kind of thing that when you do it, you should comment it.

Comment: Thanks @Alan. The intention of this script is to continuously monitor wether an SSH tunnel is opened, if not, create one. My browser use this tunnel for socks proxy. I'm by no means a competent bash coder.  The whole script was built by try-and-error. I used 'bash -i' in the hope that launching the ssh command is fork-like, rather than exec-like where the original monitoring process will stop. Please correct me with a better solution. Currently this script works fine besides generating the 'no job control' message.

Comment: What did it do differently (besides not printing the "no job control warning") when you just had the `ssh -D 7070 -N user@my-ssh.example.com > /dev/null` on a line by itself, without the `bash -i -c`?

Comment: I accidently left a '%' in front of a command (this was a file converted from a windows batch file command...); As you said, the % translates to fg, thus this error ensured

Comment: I did a `sudo su - vuXXXX` and I got that message. I can only press `CTRL+C` once then no more.

Comment: Well written, this is fun to read. Thank you!

Comment: Typically `-i` is added to bash because the behavior of the code being run requires sourcing bash startup files, like `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 27):

One of the possible options would be not having access to the tty.

Under the hood:

1. bash checks whether the session is interactive, if not - no job
   control.
2. if forced_interactive is set, then check that stderr is
   attached to a tty is skipped and bash checks again, whether in can
   open `/dev/tty` for read-write access.
3. then it checks whether new line discipline is used, if not, then job control is disabled too.
4. If (and only if) we just set our process group to our pid, thereby becoming a process group leader, and the terminal is not in the same process group as our (new) process group, then set the terminal's process group to our (new) process group.  If that fails, set our process group back to what it was originally (so we can still read from the terminal) and turn off job control.
5. if all of the above has failed, you see the message.

I partially quoted the comments from bash source code.

---

As per additional request of the question author:

http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashtop.html Here you can find bash itself.

If you can read the C code, get the source tarball, inside it you will find `job.c` - that one will explain you more "under the hood" stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a problem on my own embedded system and I got rid of the "no job control" error by running the getty process with "setsid", which according to its manpage starts a process with a new session id.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question, at best this should be a comment.

Comment: @meskobalazs No, I think this actually is answer to a problem I have, which gives the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

Faced this problem only because I've miscopied a previously executed command together with `%` prefix into zsh, like `% echo this` instead of `echo this`. The error was very unclear to such a stupid typo