# How to run shell commands in emacs on ubuntu while avoiding a bash job control error?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, emacs

I installed emacs in ubuntu (using sudo apt-get install emacs). I am havine the problem that when I try to run a shell command from within emacs (for example `M-! ls`) the output is preceded by this:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Invalid argument
bash: no job control in this shell
```

In my `.emacs` I have the option `(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")` . This is so that I can presumably use my aliases as well as commands. This has not given me issues at work and it lets me use my aliases. How can I use my aliases but avoid this problem?

Comment: You write that you use `M-x ls` to execute a shell command but AFAIK that is not a standard command. Shell commands can be run via e.g. `M-!` or `M-x shell`. Do those work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821378/what-does-bashno-job-control-in-this-shell-mean

Comment: @N.N.sorry that was a typo..I meant the regular M-! stuff which does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get my emacs to recognize my bash aliases and custom functions when I run a shell command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224909/is-there-a-way-to-get-my-emacs-to-recognize-my-bash-aliases-and-custom-functions)

Comment: What happens when you do *not* use the "-ic" switches?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that by setting your shell-command-switch like that, you are executing code paths in your `.profile` or system profile which depend on job control in shells.

I would fix this error by defining the aliases you need in the correct code paths so that that appear in shells which are not started with `-i`

You could try to swap `-i` with `--rcfile .aliases` or something similar so that `alias` in emacs does not differ from `alias` in your login shells. If your .bashrc has important stuff for your work, create a file like .bashrc.emacs with the content

```
source .bashrc
source .aliases
```

and point to that file with `--rcfile .bashrc.emacs`  in your `(setq)` instruction.

Where did you define your aliases? Ubuntus .bashrc reads .bash_aliases and that should happen also to non-interactive shells.