# Bash prompt not showing with custom Python terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am writing a terminal program in Python (in Ubuntu) and I got the communication to Bash working well. 
 I use the following command to open pipes to Bash:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I have seperate threads that handles the stdout and stderr data and I can send commands to stdin. The only thing I could not get working is that I receive a command prompt from Bash when a command is finished.

For example, if I list the directory content in an Ubuntu terminal the output is:
*cyw@cyw-VirtualBox:~/testdir$ ls -l

total 0

-rw-rw-r-- 1 cyw cyw 0 Dec  1 15:55 file1

-rw-rw-r-- 1 cyw cyw 0 Dec  1 15:55 file2

-rw-rw-r-- 1 cyw cyw 0 Dec  1 15:55 file3

cyw@cyw-VirtualBox:~/testdir*$

The same output in my Python terminal looks as follows:
*ls -l

-rw-rw-r-- 1 cyw cyw 0 Dec  1 15:55 file1

-rw-rw-r-- 1 cyw cyw 0 Dec  1 15:55 file2

-rw-rw-r-- 1 cyw cyw 0 Dec  1 15:55 file3*

All my searching on Google mostly suggests editing the $PS1 variable but I don't think this is the problem here. Without the command prompt my terminal would be very hard to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No! Don't touch `$PS1` for that! **:-D** You have to understand that `subprocess` spawns a process that runs some command, but it doesn't give you a regular terminal as you see when you log into your machine. Is not really "waiting" for user input to be typed, as your regular terminal does (`stdin` doesn't really work like that, either)

Answer (score 3):

Your `bash` is not interactive.

From [`bash(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Prompting
>
> When executing interactively, bash displays the primary prompt PS1 when it is ready to read a command
>
> Invocation
>
> <...> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments and without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.

Comment: Thank you, your answer pointed me in the right direction. I tried making the shell interactive with the -i option:  self.process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-i'], shell=False ...... Now when I run the program it sends me the following: "bash: no job control in this shell" and then it is still not interactive. Do you have any more advice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821378/what-does-bashno-job-control-in-this-shell-mean explains the reason. I dunno how to fix this atm. Ask another question since this is out of scope of this one.

Comment: I tested this and got the prompt just fine, only it was the default `$` and with error messages `inappropriate ioctl for device` and `no job control in this shell`.

Answer (score 0):

Run bash in interactive mode for PS1:

```
  p = Popen(["/bin/bash","--norc","--noprofile","-i"], shell = False,
        stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT,
        bufsize = 1,
        env={"PS1":"\\u:\\h "},
        preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```