# Why does this Java process suspend after running bash as a subprocess?

Tags: java, bash, process

If I compile and run the following Java program from bash:

```
public class BashSuspend {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("bash -i -c ls".split(" "))
                .redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT).start();
        process.waitFor();
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

I see some strange behaviour:

```
matt@Overmind:~/bash-suspend$ java BashSuspend 
BashSuspend.class  BashSuspend.java

[1]+  Stopped                 java BashSuspend
matt@Overmind:~/bash-suspend$
```

Why does the Java process suspend after running bash as a subprocess?

(I'm running openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal" on Ubuntu 15.10.)

Answer (score 0):

You program is waiting for input, which it can only do when running in the foreground.

Instead of waiting for input you ignore, I would remove it or use another approach.

Comment: The program should run in the foreground at all times. It may block while waiting for the subprocess to complete, or to read from stdin, but that's different from being suspended.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `[1]+  Stopped` due to use of:

```
bash -i
```

which is running `bash` in interactive mode. Remove `-i` option to fix this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("bash -c ls".split(" "))
```

As per `man bash`:

```
-i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
```

Also you need to comment out `System.in.read();` in order to avoid keeping your program running (it is just waiting for an input).

Just to add more info to my answer after you get `Stopped` error you can run:

```
jobs -l
```

to list background running jobs and it will show something like this:

```
[1]+ 71598 Stopped (tty input): 21 java BashSuspend
```

Which is due to your use of `System.in.read();` which is just waiting for an input in an interactive shell that doesn't have `tty` attached hence it is stopped.

Comment: I'm interested in why running "bash -i" causes the java process to suspend.

Comment: Because `ProcessBuilder` is not really running an interactive `bash`. Interactive `bash` means your usual `bash` login shell which is attached with `tty` and here we don't have any `tty` attached

Comment: I don't think so: if you just run `bash -i`, then bash starts as normal, and has a tty attached. In any case, that wouldn't explain why the parent java process is suspended.

Comment: Running `bash -i` from command line is different than running `bash -i` from Java code as you already have a `tty` attached while in a shell.

Comment: No, if you run `bash -i` from Java as a subprocess you still have a tty attached.

Comment: You code with `-i` will generate this error **bash: no job control in this shell** and [read this Q&A what it means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821378/what-does-bashno-job-control-in-this-shell-mean)

Comment: When I run the same code as posted in the question, but with just `bash -i` for the subprocess command, I get dropped into an interactive bash prompt. When I exit the bash prompt, the Java process does not suspend, but blocks for input (and then exits).

Comment: yes just `new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-i")` would work because you've removed `-c` option. Both interactive and non-interactive options shouldn't be mixed together.

Comment: I don't know whether `-i` and `-c` should or shouldn't be mixed -- I'm not too fussed, actually. I am interested in why on earth the parent Java process ends up suspended.

Comment: However `new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-i")` still won't attach a `tty` You will get `tty
tty
not a tty` error if you run `tty` command from the prompt.

Comment: Strange: when I run the `bash -i` version, then `tty` at the new prompt, I get `/dev/pts/2`.