# Error fg no job control

Tags: perl, batch-file

```
set /P Input=Options: [r]ead, [w]rite, [m]ixed:

if "%Input%"=="w" then
  perl ftl_log_read.pl random_read.txt > random_read.dat
fi

if "%Input%"=="r" then
   perl ftl_log_write.pl random_write.txt > random_write.dat
fi

if "%Input%"=="m" then
   perl ftl_log_read.pl random_rw.txt > random_read.dat
   perl ftl_log_write.pl random_rw.txt > random_write.dat
fi
```

while compiling in Linux machine I am getting "line 3: fg: no job control"

This is a run.bat file

Please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are executing a Windows batch file (.bat) as a Bash shell script. These have incompatible syntax. **You will need to rewrite the `run.bat` script as a shell script if you want to run it under Linux.**

Background:

The Bash `if` statement expects a *command* as the condition, not just a comparison expression. So `"%Input%"=="w"` will undergo variable expansion, then be invoked as a command. A string comparison would be written as `if [[ "$input" = "w" ]]; then ...; fi`. Note that shell variables look like `$name` whereas batch variables look like `%name%`.

Bash features [*job control*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824420/1521179). A shell can juggle multiple background processes. If you run a command `%foo` this will expand to the name of a background command beginning with `foo`, then bring that command to the foreground.

However, job control is only available in interactive sessions, i.e. if you use Bash as an interactive command line, not as a script interpreter. Bash therefore reports the error message “no job control” and terminates.